# Не могу найти ошибку в коде flask wt-forms

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtf

КОД(часть с ошибкой):

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, current_app, g, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_script import Manager, Command
from json import load, dump
from random import randint
from flask_wtf import Form, FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, length, Required


class RegisterLoginForm(FlaskForm):
    new_name = StringField('Login', [DataRequired()])
    new_psw = PasswordField('Password', [DataRequired()])
    new_email = StringField("Email", [Email(), DataRequired])
    name = StringField('Login', [DataRequired()])
    psw = PasswordField('Password', [DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Enter")


@app.route('/login', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    form = Form()
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('log.html', form=form)
    else:
        f = open("db.json")
        db = load(f)
        f.close()
        users = db["users"]
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            login = form.name.data
            password = form.psw.data
            for user in users:
                if login == user["login"] and password == user["password"]:
                    return render_template('cabinet.html', username=login, form=form)

        return render_template('log.html', error_message="Неверный логин или пароль", form=form)
```

ОШИБКА:

jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'flask_wtf.form.Form object' has no attribute 'login'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:
`def login():
    form = RegisterLoginForm()`